# Lockless using InterlockedCompareExchange

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, interlocked

I am trying to make following snip of code lockless using interlocked operations, Any idea how to translate this?

```
if (m_Ref == 0xFFFF)
    m_Ref = 1;
else
{
    if (++m_Ref == 1)
        CallSomething(); //

}
```

I was thinking something like

```
if (InterlockedCompareExchange(&m_Ref, 1, 0xFFFF) != 0xFFFF))
{
    if (InterlockedIncrement(&m_Ref) == 1)
         CallSomething();
}
```

Is there any issues/race in this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks correct at a superficial glance, but every time you use two interlocked operations in a row you are exposing yourself to the [ABA problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem). In this case one thread fail to change it from 0xFFFF to 1 (the ICX returns `!=0xFFFF`) so it goes ahead and takes the `if` branch and increments it. Before it runs the `InterlockedIncrement` another threads changes the `m_ref`  back to 0xFFFF and the original thread increments 0xFFFF. Depending on the type/semantics of m_ref the effect will wary, but will surely be bad.

You should do one single ICX operation, for both the 0xFFF to 1 and X to X+1, and always retry if you lost the ICX:

```
volatile <type> m_ref;

<type> ref, newRef, icxref;
do
{
   ref = m_ref;
   newRef = (0xFFFF == ref) ? 1 : ++ref;
   icxref = InterlockedCompareExchange (&m_ref, newRef, ref);
} while (icxref != ref);
if (newRef == 1 && ref != 0xFFFF)
{
   DoSomething ();
}
```

Comment: @Remus Rusanu - Thanks this makes perfect sense

Comment: @GMan: what would memory mapping have to do with `volatile`?

Comment: @Remus: That's the only use for volatile, it makes reads and writes to it observable behavior, it has nothing to do with multi-threading. Your use of it as an argument to `InterlockedCompareExchange` provides observable behavior already.

Comment: @Gman: how about the `ref = m_ref;`? W/o volatile decorator, it has no Acquire semantics.

Comment: @Remus: It doesn't have it *with* volatile... Anyway, the compiler cannot elide that assignment, because it's used in the library call later. (i.e., it has observable behavior.)

Comment: @GMan: actually it does have Acquire semantics with volatile: `A read of a volatile object (volatile read) has Acquire semantics` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd%28v=VS.100%29.aspx.

Comment: @Remus: That's a Visual Studio implementation-specific extension. Please find the equivalent quote in the C++ standard.

Comment: @GMan: ICX is a Windows library function, one is to expect VC to be used in the OP.

Comment: @Remus: You're missing the point. You still don't need `volatile` here, whether or not you get extra semantics, for the reasons I've already said.

Comment: @Remus, @Gman: There is no need for load-with-acquire in `ref = mref;`. Acquire barrier would prevent hoisting of subsequent memory operations above the load, but the very next memory operation is ICX, which has a full barrier anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there's a race. Another context could do a lot in between `InterlockedCompareExchange` and `InterlockedIncrement`

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking the same, do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Suresh: Not really, not if you want it lockless. If you can change to allow 0 then use `%` on the return value from `InterlockedIncrement`

Comment: @Suresh You can use InterlockedCompareExchange as an optimistic locking mechanism if you don't expect races to pop up too much in actual running code.